# Kubernetes - cron jobs not cleaning up pods

Tags: kubernetes

Having recently updated to version 1.22.1, we are now experiencing an issue where the existing cron jobs are no longer deleting pods once they are complete.  i have tried adding the following:

successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
failedJobsHistoryLimit: 5 to the yaml, but has had no effect.

I have also used a simple cron job example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

after 5 minutes, all the pods are still there

`kubectl get pods`

```
hello-27304804--1-q545h   0/1     Completed   0          5m21s
hello-27304805--1-b6ksd   0/1     Completed   0          4m21s
hello-27304806--1-dsvb7   0/1     Completed   0          3m21s
hello-27304807--1-bqnjg   0/1     Completed   0          2m21s
hello-27304808--1-dsv6p   0/1     Completed   0          81s
hello-27304809--1-99cx4   0/1     Completed   0          21s
```

`kubectl get jobs`

```
NAME             COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
hello-27304828   1/1           1s         2m59s
hello-27304829   1/1           2s         119s
hello-27304830   1/1           2s         59s
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `kubectl get jobs` (and format the output of `kubectl get pods`)?

Comment: I've formatted the output hopefully now more readable.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70156787/how-to-have-only-one-pod-created-for-by-cronjob/70156910

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to have only one Pod created for/by Cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70156787/how-to-have-only-one-pod-created-for-by-cronjob)

Comment: Yes i have tried all the suggestions included in mentioned post, adding activeDeadlineSeconds, ttlSecondsAfterFinished and successfulJobsHistoryLimit - nothing seems to be work

Comment: same issue for me in 1.22

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this? We're on 1.27 and the jobs are correctly removed, just the pods are remaining

Comment: Looks like this is a bug: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/74741 I've built a utility to clean up the old pods: https://github.com/davidgiga1993/cronjob-pod-cleaner

Comment: Found the root cause for us: Calico v3.26.0 causes the k8s gc to stop working: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/118753

Answer (score -1):

A workaround is setting a pod limit on a namespace via resourcequotas and sticking the cron jobs in there. Hope this helps!
src : [Unable to run .netcore app as kubernetes cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61798859/unable-to-run-netcore-app-as-kubernetes-cronjob)